# Storing and caching chat message data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, socket.io, chat

I have a chat app that works like this:

socket.io recieves message data, message data is emitted to the receiving user, message data is also pushed into redis
messages are loaded from redis on page load, and only user accounts are stored in postgres.

How can I store message data in postgres without read/write to the database everytime someone sends a message, cause you are not supposed to use redis as a primary database cause its not designed for long-term or reliable data storage?